# .NET 6 Controller Routing

Tags: c#, routes, .net-6.0

I am trying to expose all of my controllers in my .NET 6 web server application under `/api`.

Here is my current non-functional code:

```cs
// Program.cs with Minimal .NET 6 APIs
// Irrelevant and sensitive code redacted

//...

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder( args );

//...

var app = builder.Build();

//...

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthorization();

//...

app.Map( "/api", api =>
{
    api.UseRouting();
    api.UseEndpoints( endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute( "default", "/{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}" );
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    } );
} );

app.Map( "/file", file =>
{
    file.UseStaticFiles();
} );

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.MapFallbackToFile( "index.html" );

app.Run();
```

```cs
// TestController.cs

[Route( "test" )]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route( "did-it-work" )]
    public OkObjectResult DidItWork()
    {
        return Ok( "Yes." );
    }
}
```

`/file` and `/` are mapped correctly to static files, but my controllers are not exposed under `/api`. If I move `MapControllerRoute()` and `MapControllers()` to the line below `UseAuthorization()`, my controlllers are exposed at `/`.

How can I map my controllers to `/api` with the .NET 6 Minimal API?

Comment: I created a project using your code and the `DidItWork` action was mapped under `/api/test/did-it-work`